# Array intersect of array of objects

Tags: php

I have two arrays that contain friend objects. I want to find the IDs that match each other to implement mutual friends functionality. If it's too complicated using PHP, maybe I'll do it in the mysql way.

These are example array items:

```
$array1 = array(1) {
["friends_list"]=>
array(3) {
[0]=>
object(stdClass)#29 (8) {
  ["notifica_ID"]=>
  string(4) "2673"
}
[1]=>
object(stdClass)#30 (8) {
  ["notifica_ID"]=>
  string(4) "3532"
}
[2]=>
object(stdClass)#31 (8) {
  ["notifica_ID"]=>
  string(4) "3649"
}
}
}

$array2 = array(1) {
["friends_list"]=>
array(5) {
[0]=>
object(stdClass)#32 (8) {
  ["notifica_ID"]=>
  string(4) "1679"
}
[1]=>
object(stdClass)#33 (8) {
  ["notifica_ID"]=>
  string(4) "2137"
}
[2]=>
object(stdClass)#35 (8) {
  ["notifica_ID"]=>
  string(4) "3186"
}
[3]=>
object(stdClass)#36 (8) {
  ["notifica_ID"]=>
  string(4) "3187"
}
[4]=>
object(stdClass)#37 (8) {
  ["notifica_ID"]=>
  string(4) "3649"
}
}
}
```

I want to the result to be:

```
$result = array(1) {
["friends_list"]=>
array(1) {
[0]=>
array(
  ["notifica_ID"]=>
  string(4) "3649"
)
}
}
```

I have already tried `array_intersect` method but I don't know how can I implement it in array of objects.

Comment: @dave im sorry for my bad sentence.

Comment: No need to apologise. It's a community aimed at improving the questions and answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to put id's in other arrays. then do the `array_intersect` method.
this is now my answer.

```
public function mutual_friends($my_ID = '' ,$friend_ID = ''){
    if($friend_ID != '' OR $my_ID != ''){
        $myfr = $this->get_friends($my_ID);
        $frofmy = $this->get_friends($friend_ID);            
        $array1 = array();
        $array2 = array();
        foreach($myfr['friends_list'] as $row){
            $array1[] = $row->notifica_ID;
        }
        foreach($frofmy['friends_list'] as $row){
            $array2[] = $row->notifica_ID;
        }
        $result = array_intersect($array1,$array2);
        if(count($result) > 0){
            $mf = array();
            $i = 0;
            foreach($myfr['friends_list'] as $row){
                foreach($result as $row1){
                    if($row1 == $row->notifica_ID){
                        $mf[$i]['notifica_ID'] = $row->notifica_ID;
                        $i++;
                    }
                }
            }
            return $mf;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Not straightforward solution, But this will work..

```
$new_array1 =   obj_to_array( $array1["friends_list"] );
$new_array2 =   obj_to_array( $array2["friends_list"] );

$temp_result    =   array_uintersect( $new_array1, $new_array2, 'compare_values' );

$result =   array( "friends_list" => $temp_result );

function obj_to_array( $input1 )
{
    foreach( $input1 as $new )
        $temp_array[]   =   (array)$new;

   return $temp_array;
}
function compare_values($input1, $input2)
{
   return strcmp($input1['notifica_ID'], $input2['notifica_ID']);
}
```

`$result` is what you are expecting.